# Which JSTL param to use to replace: InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()

Tags: jsp, jstl

So I am trying to get rid of some scriptlets in one of the applications I took over.
One of those being: `<%=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()%>`

However I am having trouble finding the JSTL tag that gives the same result.
I thought `${pageContext.request.serverName}` would do the trick.

But the former gives the computer name when running on localhost whilst the latter returns localhost

Answer (score -1):

The former gives the computer name; the latter gives the name the client used in the URL.